# Crystal lang : Type arithmetic, belongs to a Union?

Tags: types, crystal-lang

I'm trying to implement a fucntion:

```
def foo(t : Class)
    if t in Int::Signed
        # ...
    end
end
```

But how to implement `t in Int::Signed`? Where [Int::Signed](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.0/Int/Signed.html)

I know `is_a?(Int::Signed)` but here the parameter is of type `Type`.
Thanks.

Comment: I also know `case when`, but I think it's too long and ugly.

Comment: @Amadan sorry, it's `Class`. I have corrected my question. But `typeof(1_64) == Int::Signed` returns `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def foo(t : Class)
  if t < Int::Signed
    # ...
  end
end
```

`Class#<` is only added in Crystal 0.25, if I am not mistaken, so make sure you update if it does not work for you. There is also `Class#<=` that would return `true` for `Int::Signed <= Int::Signed`.

Comment: Thanks! I was still using 0.24.2, and there wasn't this method.